# filter API response based on URL parameters that both exactly matches and also the substring of the parameter matches in Django

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-views, django-filters

I need to filter API response based on URL parameters that both exact match and also the substring of the parameter matches in Django.
The API call would be : "http://127.0.0.1:8000/showjoineduserdata?phonenumber=3349279_copy&firstname=Olivier_copy"

```
**models.py**
from django.db import models
    
class Joineduserdatanew(models.Model):
surname = models.TextField(db_column='Surname', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
firstname = models.TextField(db_column='Firstname', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
phonenumber = models.TextField(db_column='PhoneNumber', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
email = models.TextField(db_column='Email', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
login = models.TextField(db_column='Login', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
racfid = models.TextField(db_column='RACFid', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
assignee = models.TextField(db_column='Assignee', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
company_or_group = models.TextField(db_column='Company_or_Group', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
groupname = models.TextField(db_column='GroupName', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
admin = models.TextField(db_column='Admin', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
usertype = models.TextField(db_column='UserType', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
segid = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
roleid = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
segment = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
role = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'joineduserdatanew'



**serialize.py**
from dataclasses import field
from rest_framework import serializer
from usersearch_api.models import Joineduserdatanew

class JoineduserdatanewSerialization(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model=Joineduserdatanew
    fields=('surname','firstname','phonenumber','email','login','racfid','assignee','company_or_group','groupname','segment','role','admin','usertype')

**views.py**
from usersearch_api.serialization import JoineduserdatanewSerialization
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from usersearch_api.models import Joineduserdatanew
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet

class UserSearchAPIView(ListAPIView):
serializer_class=JoineduserdatanewSerialization
queryset=Joineduserdatanew.objects.all()
#filter_class = UserDataFilter
filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
filterset_fields = ['surname','firstname','login','racfid','assignee','phonenumber','company_or_group','email','segment']
```

Comment: you can use surname__contains for partial match and surname for exact match, the same will apply for rest of the fields.

Comment: Thanks,could please share where to add this,or a sample code snippet would be better

Comment: Please check the documentation here https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-and-object-lookups

Comment: Thanks, as I’m new to django l couldn’t understand this clearly and where to add those lookups so that response gets filtered as needed

Comment: can you check this library https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html?

Comment: Thanks for the solution,got it solved

Answer (score 0):

###### please install django-filter library, for installation follow this procedure

###### https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/install.html

```
import django_filters

class PostFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = {
            'title': ["exact"], # for exact match
            "desc" : ["contains"] # partial match
            # similarly you can add your new fields with filtering condition...
        }

class PostList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all() 
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_class = PostFilter
```

Comment: i need exact partial match i.e. if value in URL is "aaa" in one field, it must filter response wherein that field exactly contains "aaa" as its substring ,similarly for all fields that I have mentioned

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserSearchFilterAPIView(APIView):
def get(self,request,*args,**kargs):
    queryset=Joineduserdatanew.objects.all()
    
    #Custom filter
    
    surname=self.request.query_params.get('surname',None)
    firstname=self.request.query_params.get('firstname',None)
    login=self.request.query_params.get('login',None)
    racfid=self.request.query_params.get('racfid',None)
    assignee=self.request.query_params.get('assignee',None)
    phonenumber=self.request.query_params.get('phonenumber',None)
    company_or_group=self.request.query_params.get('company_or_group',None)
    email=self.request.query_params.get('email',None)
    segment=self.request.query_params.get('segment',None)
    if surname:
        queryset=queryset.filter(surname__icontains=surname)
    if firstname:
        queryset=queryset.filter(firstname__icontains=firstname)
    if login:
        queryset=queryset.filter(login__icontains=login)
    if racfid:
        queryset=queryset.filter(racfid__icontains=racfid)
    if assignee:
        queryset=queryset.filter(assignee__icontains=assignee)
    if phonenumber:
        queryset=queryset.filter(phonenumber__icontains=phonenumber)
    if company_or_group:
        queryset=queryset.filter(company_or_group__icontains=company_or_group)
    if email:
        queryset=queryset.filter(email__icontains=email)
    if segment:
        queryset=queryset.filter(segment__icontains=segment)
        
    serializer=JoineduserdatanewSerialization(queryset,many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Here the necessary fields are got and on each of them filters are applied, so if the API endpoint contains at least any of the parameters it filters based on it, and multiple parameters are added as 'and'.This is how I filtered the API response as needed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).